# Codeigniter Regex for URL routing Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have function call `abc`in `main` controller.

```
public function abc($value = NULL)
{
    if ($value == 10) {
         echo "value is 10";
    } else {
        echo "value is not TEN";
    } 
}
```

When i used URL route for function `abc` as following

```
http://localhost/males/7

$route['(males|female)']            = 'main/abc'; //working
$route['(males|female)/([0-9]+)']   = 'main/abc/$1'; //not working
```

But when i used separately it works. why?

```
$route['(males|female)']    = 'main/abc';
$route['males/([1-7]+)']    = 'main/abc/$1';
$route['female/([1-7]+)']   = 'main/abc/$1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $2

```
$route['(males|female)/([0-9]+)']   = 'main/abc/$2';
```

i believe $1 is matching on `(males|female)` not the digits

it works in your second case as you have dropped the first capture group and $1 is now referencing what you want.

*update as per comment;*

as per [URI routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) and regex. $1 $2 $3 are variables of the data captured from the regular expression capture groups. they are in order of the groups left to right. so in the routing rules above there are two capture groups;
$1 is `(male|female)` and $2 is `([0-9]+)`

when you changed to `$route['males/([1-7]+)']    = 'main/abc/$1';` there is now only one capture group; $1 is `([1-7]+)`

capture group (or subpattern) being whats inside `()` brackets. more [info here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)

*note: in regex these 'variables' can be referenced in 'backreferences'. more [info here](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php). you can have groups within groups, exclude patterns etc but codeigniter may have a limit on what it allows for URI routing*

Comment: working, but why $2, it is my 1st param, abc function is reference to the males or females